# i want to make the command that makes changes in the roles work in dm's in javasript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a bot that verifies people with API and stores the data in mongoose but I want the code to work in discord DMS but I have no clue how to make it give roles in a specific server when the command is run in DMS this is my code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const ignSchema = require('../schemas/ign-schema')
const mongo = require('../mongo')

module.exports = {
  commands: ['verifyme'],
  minArgs: 0,
  maxArgs: null,
  expectedArgs: "<minecraft name>",
  callback: async(message, arguments, text) => {
    const playerName = arguments.join(' ')

    fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=MYAPIKEY&name=${playerName}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(async data => {
        player = data
        const target = message.author
        const author2 = message.author.tag
        const uuid = data["player"]["uuid"]
        const discordid = data["player"]["socialMedia"]["links"]["DISCORD"]

        let verifyRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '[Verified]');
        let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
        const guildId = message.guild.id
        const userId = message.author.id
        const UUID = uuid
        const _id = UUID

        if (discordid == author2) {
          await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
            try {
              const results2 = await ignSchema.findOne({
                _id,
              })
              const {
                UUID,
                userData,
                discordName
              } = results2

              if (UUID == uuid) {
                if (author2 == discordName) {
                  if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "[Verified]")) {
                    message.reply('you are already verified')
                  } else {
                    memberTarget.roles.add(verifyRole)
                    message.reply('welcome back')
                  }
                } else {
                  message.reply(`you already used this minecraft account to verify ${discordName}, if you want to change this please contact <@390929478790152192>`)
                  mongoose.connection.close()
                  return
                }
              } else {}
            } catch {
              const userData = {
                timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
              }
              await mongo().then(async(mongoose) => {
                try {
                  await ignSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    _id
                  }, {
                    UUID,
                    discordName: author2,
                    HypixelName: playerName,
                    userId: userId,
                    guildId: guildId,

                    $push: {
                      userData: userData
                    },
                  }, {
                    upsert: true
                  })
                  memberTarget.roles.add(verifyRole)
                  message.reply('you are succesfully verified')
                } finally {
                  mongoose.connection.close()
                }
              })
            }
          })
        } else {
          message.reply(`change your linked discord account in hypixel from ${discordid} to ${author2},`)
        }
        console.log(`${discordid}`)
      })
  },
}
```

and this is the error I get:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of `null`

Comment: Why are you using `bracket["notation"]` where `dot.notation` works fine?

Comment: thats just the way i got it to work lol

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one server the bot is in, this is **not possible** without making major assumptions as to the guild they are in.

If there is only one server, `message.guild.roles` can be changed to `client.guilds.cache.get('your_servers_id').roles`.

Comment: i added this and it said  cannot read propperty of roles of undefined

Comment: Are you actually using the proper server ID? A server ID looks like `731520035717251142` (but different numbers)

Comment: yes it looks like this now `let verifyRole = client.guilds.cache.get('811543610897989683').roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '[Verified]');`

Comment: i also tried to replace find with get and some but that didnt work either

Comment: try logging what `client.guilds.cache.get('811543610897989683')` is

Comment: yeh well thats the problem it logs undefined

Comment: itried a few things but it still is undefined

Comment: Is your bot in a server with the ID `811543610897989683`? Try logging `client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.id)`.

Comment: i now get a empty [ ] but when i tried to do this before with get or find instead of map it said undifined

Comment: oh and the error i got befort is now cache instead of roles

Comment: just tried it with this code to test it and it aslo didnt work with the same  error `const theMessage = arguments.join(' ')
        
        var channel = client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.name === 'AOTG dev server').channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'aotg-log')
        channel.send(theMessage)`

Comment: i think i found the problem i didnd had client in the callback